# receive differents responses from AT command

Tags: at-command

when I send an AT command, it will be execute.
For example

```
ATD 123456789;
OK;
```

But I don't receive WCNT:*
I have maked a search on the web and i found that i should make this command: AT+WUSLMSK to receive responses. When I make it, I receive

```
AT+WUSLMSK
ERROR
```

Some one can help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified what modem/phone you are using. Are you sure that your phone supports this command? What response do you get from `AT+WUSLMSK?` and `AT+WUSLMSK=?`. Is the command listed in the output from `AT+CLAC` (this is a (optional) command that should list all supported AT commands). The AT+WUSLMSK command is not a standard one, I found [this document](http://www.multitech.com/en_US/DOCUMENTS/Collateral/manuals/S000478C.pdf) describing it and which stated that the "+WCNT:" unsolicited message is for `Call State conversation`.

Newer versions of 27.007 contains a command `AT+CMCCS - Monitor of current calls` which seem to somewhat similar (but maybe too new to be supported?). For [SonyEricsson phones](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/documentation/sony-ericsson-at-commands-online-reference/) there is the `*CPII Call progress information` UR code (enabled by AT*CPI). Maybe also `AT+CIND` can be used.